# Log4j2 lazy lambda evaluation: Any chance in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, lambda, log4j2

The problem seems to be that the pure Java implementation of Log4j2 does not offer a Closure parameter (or lambda parameter, if there is such a thing) but a simple Object parameter in the method signatures. Groovy (3.0.8) turns Java style lambdas and method references into closures and Log4j simply seems to call .toString() on them. Thus the log output for the code below, look like this, which is obviously not the expected result, coming from Java:

```
13:55:39.417 [main] INFO  Messenger - test$_runCode_closure1@f391e52
13:55:39.417 [main] INFO  Messenger - test$_runCode_closure2@4b518645
13:55:39.417 [main] INFO  Messenger - org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@294a3f2a
```

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager

def log2 = LogManager.getLogger("Messenger")

log2.info("{}", () -> "Expensive message")
log2.info ("{}") { "Expensive message" }
log2.info("{}", this::someString)

static String someString() {
    return "Expensive message"
}
```

Is there any way in Groovy to end up with a Java lambda instead of a Groovy closure here? Could a Groovy extension providing method signatures with Closure for the Logger methods be an answer?

Comment: No answer, but maybe useable as workaround: `log2.info ("${ -> "Expensive message" }")` should do what you want

Comment: @cfrick If you'd presented this as the answer, I'd voted for it. Nothing beats a good workaround, especially if it points to doing things Groovy style. Thanks.

Comment: What are the signatures available for the info method?  If you are using a lambda or method reference and it is matched to a functional interface parameter, it should be a native lambda under static compilation. However it sounds like the Object or Object... method is the one that is matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: not a proper answer, but a workaround.

Groovys GString can also work with closures, which are called each time the
GString must manifest as String.

E.g.

```
def a = 42
def gs = "${a} ${-> a}"
println gs
// → 42 42
a = 666
println gs
// → 42 666
```

So you could use:

```
log2.info ("${ -> "Expensive message" }")
```

For the record: all of those gave me the `Object` instead of `Supplier`
versions while fiddling around:

```
log2.info('{}', {42} as Supplier)
log2.info('{}', [{42}].toArray())
log2.info('{}', [{42}] as Supplier[])
log2.info('{}', [{42}] as Supplier<Long>[])
log2.info('{}', new Supplier() { Object get() { 42 } })
log2.info('{}', *[{42}])
```

Neither work with `@CompileStatic` (except the last one, which does not compile at all).  Tested with Groovy 4.0.0-alpha3

Answer (score 0):

There is a variant with just the supplier as parameter:

```
log2.info({ "Expensive message" } as Supplier)
```